# Content doesn't change when back/forward made on browser with state data in React + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to pull subreddits and show to user as a list. When user changes subreddit from options menu, I push state to browser history.

**Live Demo**: https://react-7qfrxx.stackblitz.io

Reproduction:

1. Open above link
2. Select `frontend` from list. When listed select `reactjs` again.
3. You will see URL changes (appends subreddit)
4. Now press back button of browser and forward.
5. You will see that **URL changes** but **content is the same**.

**Live Editor**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7qfrxx

*In* **AsyncApp.js** `Line 36`:

```
this.props.dispatch(push('/' + nextSubreddit))
```

How can I show previous or next cached/state to user when back/forward pressed? Can someone edit my online app to show me the correct way? I am trying to solve this since 2 days and no luck.

---

[image]

I need to do this **without** page refresh. (async)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous solution didn't work, so here's my updated answer: I think your best bet is to listen to the **`LOCATION_CHANGE`** action type of **`connected-react-router`** and to dispatch you selectSubreddit there. Using **`LOCATION_CHANGE`** is undocumented in the **`connected-react-router`** project, however the **[docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#location_change)** of the old project react-router-redux does mention it.

We can actually create a middleware function to accomplish this:

```
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'connected-react-router'
import { selectSubreddit } from './actions';

export const listenRouteMiddleware = ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (action.type === LOCATION_CHANGE) {
    const { pathname } = action.payload.location;
    if (pathname !== '/') {
      const pathArray = pathname.split('/');
      const selectSub = pathArray[pathArray.length - 1];
      next(action); // before dispatch, otherwise history breaks
      dispatch(selectSubreddit(selectSub));
      return;
    }
  }
  next(action);
}
```

Next, add it to your other middleware:

```
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'
import createRootReducer from './reducers'
import { listenRouteMiddleware } from './middleware';
export const history = createBrowserHistory()

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
  const store = createStore(
    createRootReducer(history), // root reducer with router state
    preloadedState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        listenRouteMiddleware,
        routerMiddleware(history), // for dispatching history actions
        thunkMiddleware
        // ... other middlewares ...
      ),
    ),
  )

  return store
}
```

Alter the change handler to only push the new url upon selecting an option:

```
handleChange(nextSubreddit) {
  this.props.dispatch(push('/' + nextSubreddit))
}
```

That's all! To see a working example, check out: [**Editor**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kam33v), [**App**](https://react-kam33v.stackblitz.io)

Comment: This isn't work for me. When I press back/forward content does not change. If I refresh the page then it works. I am not saying "on page load". Let say user load the page then changed options. When he go back then go forward, content does not change. I've added a GIF.

Comment: @Pratha sorry about that, you are right. My previous answer was completely wrong. Please see my updated answer for a proper solution

Comment: Thanks. This causes infinite back loop. You can go back millions time (between frontend and reactjs) but cannot go forward.  @reflexgravity' s answer works perfectly. But I loved the middleware-style. However, As I said, you can go back infinitely but can't go forward. (Even in his answer, i can go back to '/' but with your i can only go between options)

Comment: @Pratha just fixed it, had to move up the next(action) part. I was editing as you commented :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch the data based on the Route instead of the state. While selecting the dropdown, only change the route.
You can use `connected-react-router` for listening to the URL change. When a route is changed it'll fetch the data based on the Route.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  var { selectedSubreddit, postsBySubreddit } = state;

  // Listen to the connected-react-router API for URL change.
  selectedSubreddit = state.router.location.pathname === "/" ? "reactjs" : state.router.location.pathname.split("/")[1];

  const { isFetching, lastUpdated, items: posts } = postsBySubreddit[
    selectedSubreddit
  ] || {
    isFetching: true,
    items: []
  }

  return {
    selectedSubreddit,
    posts,
    isFetching,
    lastUpdated
  }
}
```

Here's the fork.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wxfdea

Here's the fixed App.
https://react-wxfdea.stackblitz.io

URLs are updated.

Comment: This isn't work for me. When I press back/forward content does not change. If I refresh the page then it works. I am not saying "on page load". Let say user load the page then changed options. When he go back then go forward, content does not change. I've added a GIF.

Comment: The issue is fixed now, I have added a listener to the connected-react-router API which will fetch the data when Route changes. See the updated code and links above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current solution is that you're storing the `selectedSubreddit` state value in two places - Redux and the url. This sort of state duplication is generally to be avoided. You're using the `connected-react-router` lib so you're not having too many problems yet, but in a larger app this sort of thing could get quite difficult to manage.

Also you have two routes in your app, `/frontend` and `/reactjs`, but you aren't defining any [`<Route/>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) components.

I think your component structure should look more like,

```
<Router>
  <>
    <Route exact path="/frontend" component={SubReddit}/>
    <Route exact path="/reactjs" component={SubReddit}/>
  </>
</Router>
```

And then in the `componentDidMount` of `<SubReddit/>` you simply inspect the `location` prop that the router supplies for the currently selected subreddit. Changing to a different subreddit is then simply a matter of navigating (use react-router's `<Link/>` component for this). In this way the url becomes to source of truth for the currently selected subreddit.

Redux is completely overkill for just managing the list of subreddit posts, but fair enough if this an exercise to use it for practice.

Comment: Thank you. Those 2 options are for example. That route is dynamic and can be anything. It can be nested too (`reactjs/another/dir/`. So i need to catch **all**.

Comment: Ok, but that shouldn't stop you using a `<Route/>` component - they support dynamic paths.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working for you is because you are only reading the subreddit name from Redux state, and not looking at the URL.  You can actually get the URL from the state, by looking at the location in the router.

So an easy fix is, instead of storing and reading the `selectedSubreddit` as a separate part of redux state, always calculate it based on the URL.  Change your `mapStateToProps` in `AsyncApp.js` as follows:

```
  const { router, postsBySubreddit } = state;
  const selectedSubreddit = router.location.pathname.substr(1) || 'reactjs';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only works for initial page load. What im trying to do is handle changes in go back/forward without page refresh and show previous or next state again. I've added a screen GIF. Please have a look at that.

Comment: @Pratha I am not sure why this didn't work for you.  Here is a fork of your original problem, with my suggested changes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9c7m23 and you can see it working here https://react-9c7m23.stackblitz.io/.